# The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: c#, badimageformatexception

I have a project in c# that uses c++ library and some dlls. When I run it it works great.

**The library is [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), contains both c++ library and c# wrappers**

When I create reference to this project from my ASP.NET MVC 4 project I get the following error:

> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
> or assembly
> 'file:///D:\Projects\Development\ProGamers\GamingSite\bin\avcodec-52.dll'
> or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
> assembly manifest.

Things I've tried:

1. Coping the dlls, but it still doesn't work (The file exists).
2. Registering it in the GAC but I've got the same error there.
3. Make sure using .NET Framework 4.0 (and not client profile)
4. [2 files with the same dll/exe name causing conflict](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/9ad17869-63cc-4529-bfaf-9099db500e0d) - I dont have it.
5. [Change the platform of the solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/41623cb4-107f-4bba-8167-4c78aad16e3b/) to AnyCPU/Mixed Platforms.

Stack Trace:

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Projects\Development\ProGamers\GamingSite\bin\avcodec-52.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +102
   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile) +34
   WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run() +190

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Projects\Development\ProGamers\GamingSite\bin\avcodec-52.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +550
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +90
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivator.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Projects\Development\ProGamers\GamingSite\bin\avcodec-52.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9850940
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +456
```

Comment: can you get a log from the binding with the [Assembly Binding log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) ? Make sure to set the settings first to Log all binds.

Comment: Assembly.LoadFrom() cannot work on a DLL like avcodec-52.dll, it is not a .NET assembly.  Why your code attempts to load it like this is entirely unclear if you don't post a snippet.

Comment: Hans I didnt use Assembly manually, and it worked great in a console application. It only makes problems only when I reference it from my ASP.NET application.

And the only use I am doing is referencing the Awesomium dlls.
http://awesomium.com

Answer (score 44):

I found that, I am using a different InstallUtil from my target .NET Framework. I am building a .NET Framework 4.5, meanwhile the error occured if I am using the .NET Framework 2.0 release. Having use the right InstallUtil for my target .NET Framework, solved this problem!

Answer (score 15):

`BadImageFormatException`, in my experience, is almost always to do with x86 versus x64 compiled assemblies.  It sounds like your C++ assembly is compiled for x86 and you are running on an x64 process.  Is that correct?

Instead of using `AnyCPU/Mixed` as the platform.  Try to manually set it to `x86` and see if it will run after that.

Comment: My machine is x86 and the c++ assembly is probably x86 as well.

I tried setting both of the projects manually to x86, but it didn't work..

Comment: This resolved my issue. Apparently my assembly was compiled for x86 and it didn't appreciate being compiled in an x64 project.

Answer (score 6):

First try to open the file with a decompiler such as ILSpy, your dll might be corrupt. I had this error on an online web site, when I downloaded the dll and tried to open it, it was corrupt, probably some error occurred while uploading it via ftp.

Comment: I didn't thought this is my case. But it was. My DLL was empty. I did not expected that from the error message.

Answer (score 3):

I got the error in the following case:

1. A .NET EXE file (#1) was referencing another .NET EXE file (#2)
2. I was trying to obfuscate EXE #2 with [Themida](https://www.oreans.com/themida.php)
3. when running the EXE #1 it was crashing with the error *"The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest"*

I simply avoided the obfuscation and the error is gone.
not a real solution, but at least I know what caused it...

Comment: For me, im obfuscating both the main application and the updater application using Reactor. This will come up almost immediately when using the x86 file stub / Native EXE options on both with ONE of them being AnyCPU. In my case, my updater must "Prefer 32bit"

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using `InstallUtil.exe` which was causing an error. To install the .`Net Core` service in window best way to use `sc` command.

More information here [Exe installation throwing error The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192900/exe-installation-throwing-error-the-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly-m)

Answer (score 2):

Check if the manifest is a valid xml file. I had the same problem by doing a DOS copy command at the end of the build, and it turns out that for some reason I can not understand "copy" was adding a strange character (->) at the end of the manifest files. The problem was solved by adding "/b" switch to force binary copy.

Answer (score 0):

I found another strange reason and i thought maybe another developer confused as me. I did run install.bat that created to install my service in **developer Command Prompt of VS2010** but my service generated in VS2012. it was going to this error and drives me to crazy but i try **VS2012 Developer Command Prompt** tools and everything gone to be OK. I don't no why but my problem was solved. so you can test it and if anyone know reason of that please share with us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the .InstallState file and reinstalling the service fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because the code was trying to create an [`AssemblyCatalog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.assemblycatalog?view=netframework-4.0) for a DLL that wasn't a C# assembly.
It was easy enough to catch the `BadImageFormatException` and ignore any such DLL.
Unfortunately, Visual Studio (at least 2017) is unable to break on `BadImageFormatException`s. (It pretends to allow that in Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System.BadImageFormatException, but it doesn't actually work.) So it took me quite a bit longer to track down this problem.