# Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0 or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, .net-assembly

I am working with webservice in C# and I am unable to run the webservice file.

Eventhough the target assemby is set to 4.5.1 I am unable to solve the error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Below is the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Below are the images displaying error message and Stack trace:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdU8b.jpg)

[Stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs3RZ.jpg)

Comment: Is this error happening in Visual Studio or on your Server? If it happens on your Server: What .NET Version is installed there?

Comment: Error is happening is Server. I am using version 4.5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226676/the-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly-manifest)

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226429/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-identitymodel-version-4-0-0-0-culture).