# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I keep seing this error under my shopping cart (The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Comment: Look at other similar questions like these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226676/the-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly-manifest it's not the same assembly but the root causes are always similar nonetheless. ie: wrong .net framework version, wrong cpu type, assembly in GAC, etc.

Comment: Do you have two projects, the main one references the other which has EntityFramework package?

Comment: This is a very general error. Could you be more specific, maybe add some code to help other identify the issue at hand? Welcome to SO!