# Exe installation throwing error The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, windows-services

I have implemented `windows service` using `.Net Core` `worker service`. When installing service from command prompt, getting error

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe D:\LC\WindowService\L3WorkerService.exe
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 4.8.3752.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 
'file:///D:\LC\WindowService\L3WorkerService.exe' or one of its dependencies. 
The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest..
```

I have tried with these two path

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe D:\LC\WindowService\L3WorkerService.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe D:\LC\WindowService\L3WorkerService.exe
```

This is my project information

- Platform target - x86
- Output type - WindowsApplication
- Target Framework - .NET Core 3.1

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you use `InstallUtil.exe` from .NET FW to install a .NET Core service?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - I am new to .Net, just followed articles to install service. How should I do it? Thank you.

Comment: You can google a little bit to find some msdn articles, like [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and follow them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To install service need to follow below steps

open `cmd` as admin and switch to output/publish dir of project. Then type

```
sc create TestService BinPath=D:\LC\WindowService/TestService.exe
```

You will get message `[SC] CreateService SUCCESS`. Other commands also available including `start` service

```
sc start TestService
sc stop TestService
sc delete TestService
```

Note: In .Net Core services avoid using `InstallUtil.exe`.